# How reinterpret_cast works when it comes to to irrelevant class?

Tags: c++, pointers, reinterpret-cast

The first two lines of output in the following code are two blank lines and the third and fourth lines are two unequal big numbers such like:
19147336
19147192

```
class A {
public:
    A() : m_i(0) { }
protected:
    int m_i;
};

class B {
public:
    B() : m_d(0.0) { }
protected:
    double m_d;
};

int main() {
    A *pa = new A;
    B *pb = new B;
    std::cout << reinterpret_cast<char*>(pa) << std::endl;
    std::cout << reinterpret_cast<char*>(pb) << std::endl;
    std::cout << (int)reinterpret_cast<char*>(pa) << std::endl;
    std::cout << (int)reinterpret_cast<char*>(pb) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I wonder what is exactly the return of reinterpret_cast in the above code. Thanks!

Comment: "irrelevant class" ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are doing undefined behaviour.  The compiler is free to to generate code that does literally anything, including creating a robot to travel back in time to douse the parents of K&R with morning after pills to prevent C from being invented in the first place.

In the first two cases above, your compiler is instead interpreting the bytes of an `int` and a `double` with value `0` as a nul-terminated array of characters, and seeing it as a 0 length buffer, so printing nothing.

In the second set of `(int)` cast cases, it is giving you an integer representation of the lower `sizeof(int)` bytes of the pointer value gotten from `new`.

Neither of these are surprising, but neither of these can be relied upon.  From strict aliasing to optimization, the compiler can do insane things when you engage in undefined behaviour, and even if you do not attach a time machine or robots, the effects of UB can occur *before the code  with UB runs*.

Comment: Upvoted. Good answer. Especially mentioning the fact that UB can affect code *before* the point of the UB itself.

Comment: @barry imagine a drone flying over them and opening a trap door.  A large drone.  With enough pills to form a fluid.  Only you can prevent unplanned UB.

Comment: Here is a link to a blog post where they discuss real code that does time travel because of undefined behaviour:  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140627-00/?p=633

Comment: And here is a link to a blog post where undefined behaviour can wipe your hard drive: https://kristerw.blogspot.com/2017/09/why-undefined-behavior-may-call-never.html

Comment: There would be no UB on ILP32  with IEEE754 floating point.  I have heard this described as "implementation-undefined", i.e. it depends on implementation-defined properties as to whether the code is UB or not

Comment: @m.m Compilers are free to define behaviour ill formed C++ programs or provise additional guanrantees on undefined behaviour.  Your claim, however, seems to be that all compilers targetring ILP32 with IEEE754 floating point do (or must?) dedine this behaviour.  I suspect you are confusing naive C++ to machine code and binary memory layout with what reinterpret cast does, which is a common misunderstanding, as its name is a bit misleading.  What is defined is a memcpy from a float to an int, *not* treating one as another, I believe.  I could be wrong.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont It is permitted to alias a standard-layout object as a character type

Comment: @m.m ah my bad; it had been so long since I wrote this answer, and I misread the question in my comment.  I saw the casting to `int` and read it as `(int)*` not `(int)`.  I'll see about fixing the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The code `reinterpret_cast<char*>(pa)` yields a pointer that points to an object of type `A`.  Because `A` is a standard-layout class,  it is well-defined to access the first data member of `A` in this way.

- `std::cout << reinterpret_cast<char*>(pa)`. You are invoking an overload of `std::operator<<` which takes `char *` second argument. This function means to output the string stored at the location. Since the value of the first `char` at that location is `0`  (since an `int` of value 0 is guaranteed to be made up of zero-valued bytes), this is well-defined and outputs a blank string.
- `std::cout << reinterpret_cast<char*>(pb)`. The representation of `double` is implementation-defined. On common IEEE754 systems then `0.0` is all bits zero so you would get a blank string as before. On other systems it would depend on their representation of numbers what happened (and may be undefined behaviour if there is no null byte).
- `std::cout << (int)reinterpret_cast<char*>(pa)` This code converts the address to `int`.  If the address cannot be represented as `int`  (this may happen on a 64-bit system), this causes undefined behaviour.  Otherwise you get a number representing the address.
- `std::cout << (int)reinterpret_cast<char*>(pb)` is similar to the previous case.